# iText C# exact text displaying

Tags: c#, itext7

I am trying to insert the exact text with the spaces at the beginning of line, however iText eats all the spaces before the first visible symbol (tabulation does't work as well).

I am using iText 7 Community edition.

C# code:

```
 FileInfo file = new FileInfo(DEST);
 file.Directory.Create();
 //Initialize PDF writer
 PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(DEST);
 //Initialize PDF document
 PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
 // Initialize document
 Document doc = new Document(pdf); 
 doc.Add(new Paragraph("Test\n\tTest\n  Test\n        Test   1 2      3"));
 doc.Close();
```

That code display the text in the output .pdf document as

```
Test
Test
Test
Test   1 2      3
```

Without any tabs and spaces before the fist visible symbol of each line.

How can I change code to get

```
Test
    Test
  Test
        Test   1 2      3
```

in the output document?

Comment: Have you tried non-breaking-spaces (0xA0)?

Comment: @mkl, yes, I tried all sorts of spaces I found in Wikipedia

`Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Test\r\tTest\r  Test\n\u0020\u2000\u2001\u2002\u2003\u2004\u2005\u2006\u2007\u2008\u2009\u200a\u200b\u202f\u205f\u2060\u3000\u00a0       Test\u0020\u0020\u00201\u00202      3");`

But it didn't work. Still same result...

Comment: Would `Paragraph.setFirstLineIndent(x)`give rise to an acceptable work-around?

Answer (score 1):

In your code example, (embedded) tabs wouldn't work in `iTextSharp` 5.xx.xx either, although spaces are respected. What's a little surprising, as you've proved, is that iText7 strips spaces following a newline. Not sure if you need support for either or both, so will give an example that handles each case separately:

First, preserving tabs:

```
Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Line 0\n")
    .AddTabStops(new TabStop(8f))
    // change to your needs  ^^
    .Add(new Tab())
    .Add("Line 1");
doc.Add(p);
```

Second, preserving spaces immediately following a newline:

```
string[] lines = "0\n1\n    2\n        3\n".Split(
    new string[] { "\n" }, 
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries
);
p = new Paragraph().AddStyle(
    new Style().SetFont(PdfFontFactory.CreateFont(FontConstants.COURIER))
);
foreach (var l in lines)
{
    if (Regex.IsMatch(l, @"^\s+"))
    {
        p.Add(" ")  // all spaces stripped, whether one or more characters
            .Add(l) // now leading whitespace preserved
            .Add("\n");
    }
    else
    {
        p.Add(l).Add("\n");
    }
}
doc.Add(p);
```

This is the first time I've looked at/written **any** iText7, so there's likely a different/better way, and I don't consider it anything but a workaround. Oddly, if you add any number of space characters following a newline **and then** immediately add a string that's also preceded with space characters, the first call strips space, but the second preserves them.

As a side note, one thing I noticed right away and *really* like about the new API is you can use method chaining all over the place. :)

Here's the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use Chunks to add text to a paragraph.

Then you should set tab settings and use specific Chunk.TABBING

```
p = new Paragraph();
p.setTabSettings(new TabSettings(56f));
p.add(Chunk.TABBING);
p.add(new Chunk("Hello World with tab."));
```

This sample is located at [iText examples](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/itext5-building-blocks/tabbing-examples)

Answer (score 0):

Just try this.

```
Font bodyFont = FontFactory.GetFont("Times New Roman", 10, Font.NORMAL);
file.Directory.Create();
//Initialize PDF writer
PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(DEST);
//Initialize PDF document
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(writer);
// Initialize document
Document doc = new Document(pdf); 

doc.Add(new Paragraph("Test", bodyFont));
doc.Add(new Paragraph("    Test", bodyFont));
doc.Add(new Paragraph("  Test", bodyFont));
doc.Add(new Paragraph("        Test 1 2   2", bodyFont));
doc.Close();
```